# Meteorjs effective display admin panel

Tags: javascript, web, meteor

I have installed meteorite, and router package

Now I have a main page app.html

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <a href="/">
        <h1>Mi page</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      {{renderPage}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Ok, now all the pages are rendered inside {{renderPage}}.

Now users go to /panel and the users panel its rendered, here is the tricky part

This section have a cpanel_nav_div and a cpanel_body, and I think its more efficient that when the user remains in the panel section the cpanel_nav_div dont renders each time the user clicks on one of panel options links, so just the cpanel_body changes.

How is the best way to do this ??

Its there a way to do other router and filter routes, so when a route matches /panel/... all the content goes inside cpanel_body instead of go inside {{renderPage}} ????

Set a Session.get and Session.set and render content inside cpanel_body depending on session (with this we miss routes)

Use routes and render cpanel_nav and cpanel_body each time ?

thx for the help

Comment: Can you post your other templates and the template logic to go with it? It's hard to understand what you're talking about without seeing the code.

Comment: when you use the router package w meteor, you have to use {{renderPage}}, and all pages are rendered there. The problem is when I want add a user panel, that panel have a custom links, that are alw the same on all the pages related to the panel, but I cant use {{renderPage}} because will render full template and I just want to render a portion of it and take advantange of the routes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell Meteor not to re-render part of your template with [preserve](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_preserve):

> You can "preserve" a DOM element during re-rendering, leaving the existing element in place in the document while replacing the surrounding HTML. This means that re-rendering a template need not disturb text fields, iframes, and other sensitive elements it contains. The elements to preserve must be present both as nodes in the old DOM and as tags in the new HTML. Meteor will patch the DOM around the preserved elements.
>
> For example, to preserve all  elements with ids in template 'foo', use:
>
> ```
>  Template.foo.preserve({
>    'input[id]': function (node) { return node.id; }
>  });
> ```

So you would probably want to use the preserve method to tell Meteor not to re-render your cpanel_nav_div element.